# How to plot a figure like Wikipedia?

Tags: python, matlab, matplotlib, plot

I'm trying to demonstrate a concept like Fourier Transform. While searching the web, I encountered an image in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform):

[image]

Is that possible to plot this figure in Python or MATLAB?

Comment: [Have a look at matplotlib.](https://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/tutorial.html) But I vote to close the question as too broad.

Comment: @Mr.T but it has a unique answer as below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at the documentatin of [plot3](https://de.mathworks.com/help/search.html?qdoc=plot3&submitsearch=) and [patch](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/patch.html) as well as some standard plot tools.

This code produces the following image:

```
t = 0:.01:2*pi;
x1 = 1/2*sin(2*t);
x2 = 1/3*sin(4*t);
x3 = 1/4*sin(8*t);
x4 = 1/6*sin(16*t);
x5 = 1/8*sin(24*t);
x6 = 1/10*sin(30*t);

step = double(x1>0);
step(step==0) = -1;
step = step*.5;

figure
hold on
plot3(t,ones(size(t))*0,step,'r')

plot3(t,ones(size(t))*1,x1,'b')
plot3(t,ones(size(t))*2,x2,'b')
plot3(t,ones(size(t))*3,x3,'b')
plot3(t,ones(size(t))*4,x4,'b')
plot3(t,ones(size(t))*5,x5,'b')
plot3(t,ones(size(t))*6,x6,'b')

plot3([2*pi+.5 2*pi+.5],[.5 6],[0 0],'b')
plot3([2*pi+.5 2*pi+.5],[1 1],[0 1/2],'b')
plot3([2*pi+.5 2*pi+.5],[2 2],[0 1/3],'b')
plot3([2*pi+.5 2*pi+.5],[3 3],[0 1/4],'b')
plot3([2*pi+.5 2*pi+.5],[4 4],[0 1/6],'b')
plot3([2*pi+.5 2*pi+.5],[5 5],[0 1/8],'b')
plot3([2*pi+.5 2*pi+.5],[6 6],[0 1/10],'b')

hold off
view([45,45])
patch([0 2*pi 2*pi 0 0],[0 0 0 0 0],[-1 -1 1 1 -1],'g','FaceAlpha',.3,'EdgeColor','none')
patch([2*pi+.5 2*pi+.5 2*pi+.5 2*pi+.5 2*pi+.5],[.5 6 6 .5 .5],[-1 -1 1 1 -1],'g','FaceAlpha',.3,'EdgeColor','none')

zlim([-1,1])
xlim([-.5,2*pi+.5])
ylim([-.5,6.5])

axis off
```

[image: tmp]

It could serve you as a start point.

Since you already read the article about `fft` I leave the red plot as an exercise to yourself ;-)

Answer (score 0):

The function to plot 3D lines is `plot3`

The following code will produce the various lines

```matlab
T=(0:.01:2).';
X = repmat(1:6,[length(T),1]);
phase = bsxfun(@times,T*2*pi,1:2:11);
Z = 4/pi*bsxfun(@rdivide,sin(phase),1:2:11);

Xsum = zeros(size(T));
Zsum = sum(Z,2);

figure;
plot3(X,T,Z,'b');
hold on
plot3(Xsum,T,Zsum,'r');
```

`patch` objects with an alpha channel can be used for the grey surfaces.

```matlab
Xpatch=zeros(4,1);
Ypatch= [0 2 2 0].';
Zpatch= [2 2 -2 -2].';
patch(Xpatch,Ypatch,Zpatch,[.5 .5 .5],'FaceAlpha',.3,'EdgeColor',[.5 .5 .5]);
% patch(X,Y,Z,FaceColor_RGB_triplet,'Name','Value',...)
% FaceAlpha : transparency
% EdgeColor : RGB triplet for the edge
```

The same can be used to plot the frequency spectrum